# Как правильно написать "if else" в теле "for" без повторений

Tags: html, алгоритм, frontend, code-style, velocity

Мой код ревьювер сказал, изменить текущий так как он не соответсвует принципу "Don't repeat yourself" [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
Конструкцию if else надо изменить. Технология ".vm", java apach velocity template, но думаю это не очень важно.

```
#set($first = "true")
#foreach($item in $data)
    #if($first == "true")
        <div class="tabs first" id="$item.get('Key')">
        #set($first = "false")
    #else
        <div class="tabs" id="$item.get('Key')">
    #end
        <h1>str1</h1>
        <h1>str2</h1>
        <h1>str3</h1>
    </div> ##//Close div created in (if else)
#end
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<div class="tabs 
#if($first == "true")
     first
    #set($first = "false")
#end
" id="$item.get('Key')">
```

Но, на мой взгляд, это типичный пример принесения читаемости кода в жертву догматическому следованию "принципу".

Answer (score 4):

Признак первого элемента при переборе можно [получить из переменной `$foreach`](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#variables): `$foreach.first`

Следовательно код может принять вид:

```
#foreach($item in $data)
    <div class="tabs #if($foreach.first) first#end" id="$item.get('Key')">
        <h1>str1</h1>
        <h1>str2</h1>
        <h1>str3</h1>
    </div> ##//Close div created in (if else)
#end
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать упростить до:

```
#set($first = "first")
#foreach($item in $data)
    <div class="tabs $first" id="$item.get('Key')">
        ...
    </div>
    #if($first == "first")
        #set(first = "")
    #end
#end
```

<sup>не знаком с этим языком шаблонов, поправьте. Идея ясна должна быть</sup>